# Subsetting a logical vector with a logical vector in R

Tags: r, subset, logical-operators

(Note: following the suggestions in the comments, I have changed the original title "Comparing the content of two vectors in R?" to "Subsetting a logical vector with a logical vector in R")

I am trying to understand the following R code snippet (by the way, the question originated while I was trying to understand [this example](https://rdpeng.github.io/Biostat776/lecture-scoping-rules-of-r.html#application-optimization).)

I have a vector `a` defined as:

```r
a = c(FALSE, FALSE)
```

Then I can define `b`:

```
b <-  a
```

I check `b`'s content and everything looks OK:

```
b
#> [1] FALSE FALSE
```

**Question**

Now, what is the following code doing? Is it checking if `b` is equal to "not" `a`?

```
b[!a] 
#> [1] FALSE FALSE
```

But if I try `b[a]` the result is different:

```
b[a] 
#> logical(0)
```

I also tried a different example:

```
a = c(FALSE, TRUE)
b <-  a
b
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Now I try the same operations as above, but I get a different result:

```
b[!a] 
#> [1] FALSE
b[a] 
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I wasn't even sure about what could be the proper title for this question... feel free to recommend another title or edit the title directly if you have a better idea.

Comment: True/false inside square brackets will result in displaying those values which are at true index

Comment: You are not "comparing", I would rather describe it as indexing or subsetting. Please study `?Extract` and [R Intro 2.7 Index vectors; selecting and modifying subsets of a data set](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-vectors). For comparison, see `?Comparison` and e.g. [R Intro 2.4 Logical vectors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Logical-vectors) Cheers

Comment: For logical vectors, comparisons are done with operators like `==` (equals), `&` (and), `|` (or). As other have said, `[]` is used for subsetting or indexing.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik and Gregor Thomas, I have changed the tiltle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` is used for subsetting a vector. You can subset a vector using integer index or logical values.

When you are using logical vector to subset a vector, a value in the vector is selected if it is TRUE. In your example you are subsetting a logical vector with a logical vector which might be confusing. Let's take another example :

```
a <- c(10, 20)
b <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
a[b] 
#[1] 10
```

Since 1st value is `TRUE` and second is `FALSE`, the first value is selected.

Now if we invert the values, 20 would be selected because `!b` returns `FALSE  TRUE`.

```
a[!b]
#[1] 20
```

Now implement this same logic in your example -

```
a = c(FALSE, FALSE)
b <- a
```

`!b` returns `TRUE TRUE`, hence both the values are selected when you do `b[!a]` and the none of the value is selected when you do `b[a]`.

Answer (score 1):

`b[!a]` will result in displaying those values of b which are at TRUE positions as evalauted by `!a`.

`!a` is actually T, T therefore displays first and second values of b which are F and F

More efficiently please see this

```
a <- 1:4
b <- c(T, T, F, T)
```

now `a[!b]` will display `a[c(F, F, T, F)]` i.e. only third element of `a`